# Error in drawing a Piecewise function!

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I want to plot the piecewise function (FP), which is define as:

$$FP=\cases{1,&$\text{Eta}<J$\\
        \frac{1-\left| \text{Gam}\right| }{2}, &$\text{Eta}=J$\\
\frac{\left| \text{Gam}*J\right| }{\text{Eta}}, &$\text{Eta}>J$\\}$$

where $J=1$, $\text{Gam}=\frac{8}{10}$, and $\text{Eta}=\sqrt{B^2+\text{Gam}^2 J^2}$
According to the ref. "10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.107901" I already know that the resulting curve should be as shown in Fig. (a). But I get Fig. (b).

[image]

The code I used is:

```
J = 1; Gam = 8/10; 
Eta = Sqrt[B^2 + J^2 Gam^2];
FP = Piecewise[{{1, Eta < J}, {(1 - Abs[Gam])/2, 
     Eta == J}, {(Abs[J Gam])/Eta, Eta > J}}] ;
Plot[FP, {B, 0, 3}, Exclusions -> None]
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Just from simple algebra, it seems clear to me that the first graph (Fig. (a)) does not match the formula.  Note that `Plot` will not plot isolated points.  Those have to be added by the user.  The option `Epilog` is a common way to do that.

Comment: Maybe you want something like `ListLinePlot@Table[FP, {B, 0, 3, 1/100}]`.  It looks close to Fig. (a), but mathematically, it's inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want this?:

```
Plot[FP, {B, 0, 3}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> {Automatic, {0.6}}]
```

[image]

Or more generally,

```
excl = Values@Solve[And @@ # && 0 < B < 3, B] & /@ 
     Visualization`ExpandExclusions[FP, {B}, Automatic] //
    Flatten // 
   Union;
Plot[FP, {B, 0, 3}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> {Automatic, excl}]
```